# Cart Price Rules Help

Tags: magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules, price-rules

I am trying to setup a cart price rule but I can't seem to get it working. I am on Magento CE 2.1.5

I offer 4 price categories of products (elite, premium,standard etc...). If you buy two of the same category, you save $5.

I have it setup like this:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
-If total quantity  is  1  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions: 
-Price Category  contains  Standard  

-If total quantity  is  1  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions: 
-Price Category  contains  Standard
```

When I go to the frontend, add two products that are standards, I see a discount of $10 (even though I set $5). Then when I go to checkout, and calculate shipping, the discount disappears.

The actions are as follows:

[image]

I cleared my cache and history, and reindexed.

Ideas? I also tried:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
-If total quantity  is  2  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions: 
--Price Category  contains  Premium
```

But that didn't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

If $5 is the max that you will offer per two items in that category, you can apply a fixed discount for the whole cart for each category like this:

[image: Conditions]

(It appears Price Category is a custom attribute for you, so I just used Category.)

[image: Actions]

You would set up a price rule like the above for each Price Category to receive an additional $5 discount for buying two products in that category.

The caveat is that this method wouldn't work if you want to offer $10 off for buying 4 products ($15 for 6, etc.) in the **same** category. I suppose you could set the condition to be precisely quantity 2 instead of "equals or greater than" and precisely quantity 4 and so on for each Price Category, but that seems awfully tedious.